# How to stop useEffect from running after a state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

The problem here is that when a user logs out, `isAuthed` becomes `null` (as expected) and this fires `useEffect()`, then `isAuthed` becomes `false`. Because of this, when a user logs in, logging in is successful, but `isAuthed` is already `false` so that the private route is not called. How do I solve this problem?

The state is handled by Redux. The initial value of `isAuthed` is `null`.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <PublicRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, isAuthed, ...rest }) {
  
  async function verifyUser() {
    const res = await fetch(,);    // call users/me endpoint
    if (res.status === 200) {
      // dispatch action to change `isAuthed` to `true`

    } else {
      // dispatch action to change `isAuthed` to `false`
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthed === null) {
      verifyUser();
    }
  }, [isAuthed]);


  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => isAuthed == null ? "loading" :
        isAuthed == true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
    />
  );
};
```

```
function PublicRoute({ component: Component, isAuthed, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => isAuthed == false || isAuthed == null ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />}
        />
    )
};
```

```
 const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const res = await fetch(,);    // call login endpoint to check user credentials
        if (res.status === 200) {
            props.history.push('/dashboard');
         
        } else {}
```

Comment: You want to make sure that `isAuthed` is always null just before a user tries to login. Am I correct?

Comment: Hi Harsh. Yes, that's right. I'm thinking that another Redux state like isLoggedOut to track a user action might solve this.

Comment: If yes, then why don't you try to change `isAuthed` to `null` in the first line of handleLogin?